# Decompiling an APK of Unity framework with IL2CPP

Tags: decompilation

Is it actually possible to decompile the source code from .so files (in this case it's libil2cpp.so) inside the APK of Unity with IL2CPP scripting backed?

I tried stuff like https://github.com/Perfare/Il2CppDumper and a few more tools, but it only allows me to see the structure of the project like methods with offset, etc., but nothing about the source code.